# Android - Admob pushing layout down

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob, gesture

I have released an app, but the problem is with admob pushing the layout, say you start drawing a gesture as soon as you open the activity then after a couple of seconds a ad pops up, it pushes the content and as a result ruins the gesture you've drawn.

How can I stop this from happening, I want the ad to load but not push the what's underneath it.

I have included the XML of my create gesture layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gridbg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

   <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
         android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId=""
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gestures_overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gestureColor="#00FFFF"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done"

            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:enabled="false"

            android:onClick="addGesture"
            android:text="@string/button_done" 

            style="@style/BlueButtonText"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="cancelGesture"
            android:text="@string/button_discard" 

            style="@style/BlueButtonText"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pushing your view because you set the height to wrap_content. When the view first loads, there is no ad to display, so the height is zero. Try setting the height of the container view so the view always takes up the space you need for your ad:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

   <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
         android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId=""
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Optionally, he could also get rid of the LinearLayout altogether and just put `layout_height="50dp"` on the com.google.ads.AdView.

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag Very true. I usually like to slap a background behind my ads so they are a bit more palatable, so mine are usually wrapped.

Comment: How can we set height for smart banners? Please suggest what to do in case we use smart_banners

Answer (score 0):

if you won't get an ad , you will end up with empty space ,which will look weird and waste valueable space on small screens .

not only that , but according to what i know , the ad is supposed to be in different sizes on different screens .

i think you should consider doing the next things :

1. put the ad on top of the layout
2. put it only on places that it's not important that the user would see. maybe even on splash screens ,transition screens , and settings page
3. use an animation for when the ad shows up , and when it finishes , change the layout too.

Comment: some very good points, but I think what I will do is if a ad does not load I bring my own advert linking to one of my apps.

Comment: yes, that's a nice idea too. what would you do , though , if an ad is shown just when the user is trying to click on your own banner of the app? wouldn't it be weird for the user?

Comment: What I would do is change the way it loads an ad, at the moment I'm just using XML, but to detect if a ad has not loaded and then load my own banner or even a ad from another network like iad I would have to load it in the code. I wouldn't have my banner there as default I would load it programmatically

Comment: not sure i understand. if the ad isn't shown yet , would you show something instead? if not , and the ad was received , you will probably wish to show it. and if the answer is yes , you would have the ad replace what was shown before , having the problem i've just described.

Comment: I will only load a ad when the activity is started, so it will either be admob ad or my banner. Granted there might be a few seconds at the start where nothing is there, but I feel that's a lot better than having nothing there at all. Also say if the activity fails to load ad and then loads my banner and then in 60 seconds it refresh's then it does load ad replacing my banner. I see this no different from how admob works where you can set the refresh rate.

Comment: so you end up with the problem i've introduced : the user is about to click on your banner , but instead the click was done on the admob banner .

Comment: I understand your point but I still see this no different than a ad refresh, where you can set the ad refresh interval. I mean it's happened to me when I have wanted to click on a ad and then I end up clicking on a new ad replacing it.

Comment: yes , you are correct . i guess it's ok then. reminds me of times where i drive the car at a junction and then the cars in front of me stop while the traffic light changes to red . there is nothing i can do since i'm in the middle of the junction.